# document.getElementById('').src == ??? (is equal to FAIL)

Tags: javascript

My javascript is

```
function changeImage(imgID) {
var baseurl = "media/images/";
if (document.getElementById(imgID).src == baseurl+"selection-off.png") {
    alert('Success');
    document.getElementById(imgID).src = baseurl+"selection-no.png"; }
else {
    alert('Fail'); } }
```

and my HTML is

```
<div id="mustard" class="checkbox"><img id="mustard-img" class="no-off" src="media/images/selection-off.png" alt="checkbox" onClick="changeImage('mustard-img')" /></div>
```

I always get Fail when clicking the image. I must be missing something really elementary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers convert the `img` src to the full url (including `http://www....`)

try alerting it to make sure..

You could use the

```
document.getElementById(imgID).src.indexOf( baseurl+"selection-off.png" ) >= 0
```

which checks if one string is contained in the other..

Comment: That was it exactly. Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: @pattern, not really. It is how the browser represents url paths internally.. We can only work around it ..

Answer (score 2):

Alert string document.getElementById(imgID).src. It might be taking complete path i.e. including host name while the string you are comparing with has relative path.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on my own server.

**Result:**

`document.getElementById(mustard-img).src` is 
'`http://localhost/webfiles/media/images/selection-off.png'`

`baseurl+"selection-off.png"` is '`media/images/selection-off.png`'

baseurl seems to show the relative url only.
So that is the reason why "Fail" gets alerted.

Comment: Also I would advise using sprites when you have to swap images (although you are using an <img> element in this case). Then you just change the offset of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following code:

```
 <div id="mustard" class="checkbox"><img id="mustard-img" class="no-off" src="media/images/selection-off.png" alt="checkbox" onClick="changeImage(this)" /></div>

 <script>
 function changeImage(img) {
  if (img.src.indexOf('selection-off.png')) {
      alert('Success');
      img.src.replace(/selection-off.png/, 'selection-no.png');
  }else{
      alert('Fail');
  }
 }
 </script>
```

The differences with your code:

- passing the img reference: `this` instead of the id in the onclick function
- use `indexOf` instead of ==, for relative paths

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the DOM is built when the script is loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the src attribute is changed by the browser.  Don't do it that way, the proper way to check and change the css class or style attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

Image-based checkboxes are quite common, but here is the full solution.

1) Render actual checkboxes first. These work for 100% of browsers.

2) When the page loads, place your "image checkbox" next to the checkbox and hide the checkbox

3) When the image is clicked, toggle the checkbox and use the hidden checkbox to ascertain the state of the image.

When the form is POST-ed, the checkboxes will act like normal checkboxes. If JavaScript is disabled or otherwise not available the form is still usable.